# Two Cards are drawn from the standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the ff. occur?

Tags: probability

Two Cards are drawn from the standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the ff. occur?
  A. Both aces or both face cards 
     B. Both aces or both red

my answer on letter a is $\frac{12}{221}$ while the answer key is $\frac{4}{13}$. Which one is correct? Or both are wrong?

My solution: $\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)$$\left(\frac{3}{51}\right)$+$\left(\frac{12}{52}\right)$$\left(\frac{11}{51}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{1}{221}\right)$+$\left(\frac{11}{221}\right)$ = $\frac{12}{221}$

same on letter b, my answer is $\frac{336}{1326}$ but i ther's no such answer on the choices: $\frac{1}{221}$$\frac{25}{102}$$\frac{25}{221}$$\frac{83}{102}$. Which is the correct answer?

My solution: $\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)$$\left(\frac{3}{51}\right)$+$\left(\frac{26}{52}\right)$$\left(\frac{25}{51}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{1}{221}\right)$+$\left(\frac{25}{102}\right)$ = $\frac{336}{1326}$

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you arrived at your answers.  That helps users detect the source of any errors you may have made.

Comment: $\frac 4{13}$ is far too large...that's over $30\%$!  Indeed, $\frac {16}{52}=\frac 4{13}$ is the probability that the first card is an ace or a face card.

Comment: Your computation for $a$ is correct.  For $b$ you double count the cases where you get two red aces.  Note: Even with the corrected expression, I don't see a match amongst the official answers.

Comment: Also note:  $\frac 4{52}\times \frac 3{51}+\frac {26}{52}\times \frac {25}{51}=\frac {331}{1326}$.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to answer b?

Answer (score 1):

For part $a$ your computation appears to be correct. Indeed, the official answer, $\frac 4{13}$ is clearly too large...that's the probability that the first card is either an ace or a face card.

For part $b$, first of all you have an arithmetic error as $$\frac 4{52}\times \frac 3{51}+\frac {26}{52}\times \frac {25}{51}=\frac {331}{1326}$$

More importantly, your expression double counts the cases where you get two red aces.  As there are two such cases (depending only on the order) you ought to have written $$\frac 4{52}\times \frac 3{51}+\frac {26}{52}\times \frac {25}{51}-\frac 2{52}\times \frac 1{51}=\frac {55}{221}$$

Note that this answer doesn't appear on the official list of options.

Comment: a very large thanks man